# How to disable / modify AJAX validation on Hierarchical Select module?

Tags: taxonomy-terms

I'm using the Hierarchical Select module for Drupal 7. In my form, there are also some required text fields. When I click the Hierarchical Select element to choose a value, several validation errors for the unfilled, required text fields appear above the HS element.

How can I prevent these validation errors from appearing?

Comment: These errors are bugs with the module (Hierarchical Select does not have a stable Drupal 7 release) and thus off topic for *Drupal Answers*.  That said, you can hide the validation errors by turning error reporting off.

Comment: I think this new user should have linked to a bug report he created on the module page and then linked here for added visibility. That is the very point of this place, in my opinion and falls within my interpretation of the FAQ's. At the very least it should not have been down voted especially without comments explaining to the user why it was down voted.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I wasn't sure if this was a module bug or just a problem with my implementation. However on second glance it appears the module hasn't been updated in over a year.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the brand new [Simple hierarchical select](http://drupal.org/project/shs) module if it fits your needs. I used it and it's working great.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I ended up using a Forms API based solution, but the module you suggest looks promising. I may give it a look in the future.